# Equations of Motion of a Physical Pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I would like to formulate the equations of motion of a particular type of physical pendulum, shown in the attached figure.
[image: Physical pendulum with rolling friction]

The physical pendulum consists of a wheel rolling on a narrow board.  A pendulum arm grips the wheel and hangs down to a weight.  As the pendulum swings, the wheel rolls along the wooden surface.

I am having trouble working the knowledge that the centre of rotation of the wheel is undergoing translation in the horizontal direction.

**System parameters:**
- L, the  distance from the wheel axis to the pendulum's centre of mass, **is known** 
- the mass of the wheel, m, and the mass of the pendulum assembly, M, **are known**

**Goal:**
 - to find the coefficient of rolling friction (mu_rolling) between the wheel and the wooden board
 - to find the moment-of-inertia of the wheel (Iw) alone

**Method:**
- I would like to determine the equations of motion of the pendulum-wheel assembly in dynamical form using *x*, *d(x)/dt*, *theta* and *d(theta)/dt* as state variables.

Can anyone offer any help in building the equations?

Comment: First, can you express the $x$ coordinate of the upper wheel as a function of $\theta$? Hint: Consider the cases $\theta=0,\,\pi/2,\,\pi$.

Comment: Sure, x = R  * $\theta$

So now we're down to just the angular equations.  Ok.
$$
$d(\theta)/st = alpha$ 

$d(\alpha)/dt = $1/I * ( - L m g sin(\theta) - sign(\alpha) \mu m g  )

Comment: Right. One way forward would be to construct the Lagrangian for the system, as a function of $\theta$ and $\dot{\theta}$, and then employ the Euler-Lagrange equations... Although, on second thought, this may not be the easiest way given the need for a dissipation function to account for friction...

Comment: Will that work for a non-conservative system (we have friction)?

Comment: When you say *rolling resistance* please define what friction force you have in mind: $F_f=f(v_{wheel})$.

Comment: $F_f = \mu N$  -> Simple  contact friction model proportional to the normal force. 
  
Also known as kinetic coeff of friction.

Comment: interesting problem considering the frictional force component can turn out to be a function of the pendulum angle since the vertical component of the wheel contact force changes - maximum weight will be at bottom dead center. The system undoubtedly nonlinear and I wouldn't be surprised if the motions turn out to be chaotic given the size of initial condition and coefficient of friction.

Comment: Right. The system is weakly nonlinear.  I just want to formulate the system of equations and then use Octave to simulate the system.  Fun, ain't it?  :-)

Comment: This is not a homework question, btw.   I am an engineer working on evaluating bicycle wheels and trying something crazy.

Comment: Without friction this problem can be easily treated by constructing the lagrangian of the system and using Euler-Lagrange equation. With friction this becomes trickier.

Comment: Hi AndyF. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: All I can say is that this really isn't a homework question, and my goal is to get the governing equations of motion so that I can interpret experimental results.

Comment: @Qmechanic : The only way in which this problem is in breach of policy is that the OP does not demonstrate sufficient effort to derive the equation of motion himself.  The only way to rectify this is to post such an attempt.  However, that has already been done in the 2 Answers.  It would be pointless to copy and paste one of these Answers into the question.  So what does the OP have to do to put the question back 'on topic'?

Comment: Thank you for asking a very pertinent question, @sammy gerbil.

I will attempt a Newtonian formulation and maybe we can reconcile the terms with the Lagrangian method suggested to us by Ilya Lapan.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Let $x_1,\theta_1$ etc. with subscript 1 be coordinates of the upper mass, and variables with subscript 2 be coordinates of the second mass. So,the Lagrangian can be constructed as:
$$ L = 1/2M\dot x_1^2 + 1/2 \ I\dot \theta_1^2+ 1/2m\dot x_2 + 1/2m\dot y_2^2 - mgy_2$$

Now, $$ y_2 = L \ cos(\theta_2) \\ x_2 = x_1 + L \ sin(\theta_2)$$
I think that accounts for all relevant constraints. I think that leaves us with 3 generalised coordinates, and thus 3 equations, I think (sorry, my memory is a bit rusty on this topic). Substituting in and using Euler-Lagrange equation would give the right result, if there was no friction:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x_1} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta_1} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_1} \ \ \ \ (2)$$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta_2} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_2} \ \ \ \ (3)$$
Now you just need to take the derivatives and that would give you your 3 equations of motion. So even without friction you get 3 coupled differential equations, so I would expect something very chaotic. 
 To account for friction you need to insert a dissipative function into Euler-Lagrange equation and that would depend on what kind of friction we are modelling. Or we could find some other clever way to reintroduce the friction afterwards as some sort of correction (after we have our equations of motion). Because this feels is kinda the same result that Newtonian approach would produce, but derived in a more straightforward fashion,  I was thinking to just stick friction as drag and torque terms into equation 1 and 2, but I am not sure if that is allowed (if someone, who has better understanding, can tell me whether or not I am allowed to do that I would really appreciate that).

EDIT: Just realised that if you model this system with simple static, velocity independent friction there is no reason to actually treat the upper mass as wheel, it could as well be a point mass on a rail, rotational motion of upper mas plays no role on motion of the lower mass.

Comment: what is $\theta_2$?

Comment: @AndyF Orientation of the upper mass is $theta_1$. It is an arbitrary variable, doesn't matter what it's absolute value is, the main point is that its time derivative, $\dot \theta_1$, is the angular velocity of the upper mass. The angle that the metal arm connecting two masses makes with y-axis is $theta_2$. I have added a diagram, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rolling pendulum.]

Consider the arm to be massless and of length $L$.

Two torques now act on the wheel:

$F_1L=mgL \sin \theta $

And:

$F_fR=\mu NR$

With:

$N=Mg+mg=(M+m)g$

So:

$F_f=\mu (M+m)gR$

Newton's second law (here on rotation) tells us:

$$I\alpha=-mgL\sin \theta+\mu (M+m)gR$$
Or:
$$I\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+mgL\sin \theta=\mu (M+m)gR$$

If we accept the small angle approximation:

$$\sin \theta \approx \theta$$

$$I\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+mgL\theta=\mu (M+m)gR$$

This the equation of motion of a simple harmonic oscillator *and can of course not be the true equation of the system*, as the rolling resistance definitely acts as a damper.

The problem is that $F_f$ as defined here doesn't even change direction.

To obtain something like the OP's second sketch, that is an [Underdamped Oscillation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html#c2), $F_f$ would have to be of the form:

$$F_f=-c\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

Comment: I don't see how normal force is just $mg + Mg$. The lower mass is not in equilibrium, so the tension in the rod is not equal to $mg$ and so the downward force from the rod on the upper mass is not $mg$.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Ilya .   I disqualified my own answer because of this.  We also don't need any small-angle approximations, since it's the exact problem formulation that interests me - not the solution.   I will simulate as much nonlinearity as is required.  
<br/>
My first try was to use this:
<br/>
$
\dot{\theta} = \alpha \\
\dot{\alpha} = \frac{1}{I_t} ( - (m + M) g L sin(\theta) - sign(\alpha) \mu (m + M) g )
$

Comment: @AndyF I think this really requires Lagrangian dynamics. I outlined how it could be done in my answer, but you need to take a look how Lagrangian dynamics deals with friction in such problems.